# Should I use special user for pm2 to run my express app?

Tags: pm2, user-permissions

Does it make sense / is it absolutely essential to run pm2 through a special dedicated user on linux host? I want to run my express app and restart it whenever it crashes. From nginx/apache I am used to having special users that run the processes. It introduces obviously some hassle with permissions. But in almost no tutorials / articles do I see people making the effort of creating a new user and using it to run their express apps. More over, it looks like pm2 is running as root daemon on the system, is that true, or did I configure it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, install pm2 with root, check out: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/#user-permissions - then just remember to `npm install` your app as the user which will run it, just so no node_modules permission issues.

Comment: A tut can be found here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-pm2-to-setup-a-node-js-production-environment-on-an-ubuntu-vps

Comment: I would suggest that you run pm2 the same user that you run your express app, and if you need the process to start at boot, you'll also need to give the user sudo privilege. Also depending on the port that your express app is using, a non-privileged user might have trouble running the application if the port number is under 1024, see [https://serverfault.com/questions/84360/regular-user-using-ports-below-1024](https://serverfault.com/questions/84360/regular-user-using-ports-below-1024). I am using pm2 in many applications and none of them I am running pm2 as root.